# How does greater than comparison operator on NVARCHAR field works in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I was reviewing a code in order to rewrite the logic for migration purpose and I encountered ">" operator used on NVARCHAR column.

Sample:

```
SELECT COL_A, COL_B FROM TBL WHERE COL_C > ''
```

What does it really accomplish? It would make sense if it was done over numerical values.

I have noticed that it eliminates record with white spaces in COL_C. Does it do anything more than that?

How does this work internally? Which value does SQL Server compare it with?

Thanks

Comment: Got it. Thank very much.

Comment: Glad we could help.